# Amplify/Cognito no analytics data showing in Pinpoint

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

No data from my user events is showing up in pinpoint.

I have a frontend react native app which uses the Amplify Auth library configured as:

```
    Amplify.configure({
      Analytics: {
        AWSPinpoint: {
          region: ENV.REGION,
          appId: ENV.PINPOINT_APP_ID,
        },
      },
      Auth: {
        region: ENV.REGION,
        userPoolId: ENV.USER_POOL_ID,
        userPoolWebClientId: ENV.USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID,
        authenticationFlowType: ENV.AUTHENTICATION_FLOW_TYPE,
        oauth: {
          domain: ENV.OAUTH_DOMAIN,
          scope: ["email", "openid", "profile"],
          redirectSignIn: appConfig.scheme,
          redirectSignOut: appConfig.scheme,
          responseType: "code",
          urlOpener,
        },
        federationTarget: "COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
      },
..
```

In the backend I connected Cognito with pinpoint and use an IAM role with the following policies:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-idp:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "mobiletargeting:UpdateEndpoint",
                "mobiletargeting:PutEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:mobiletargeting:eu-west-1:73463623453:apps/my-pinpoint-project-id/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I use the app to log in. No data appears in pinpoint.

However, when I do the same using the cli, then the data does show up in pinpoint:

```
AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=novasport-dev aws cognito-idp initiate-auth --auth-flow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH --auth-parameters USERNAME=05ac342c-2134-48f9-b124-b1favc5d0bb1,PASSWORD=myPwd --client-id myWebClienId --analytics-metadata AnalyticsEndpointId=my-pinpoint-project-id
```

It seems like in my FE app the Amplify `Auth` library is not able to send the data to pinpoint. When I track the network request I also don't see a call being executed that represents the analytics data.

How can I get the analytics data from my FE app to Pinpoint? Am I missing some configuration?

**EDIT**

We are using the modular imports of Amplify as such

```
import Amplify from "@aws-amplify/core";
```

`package.json`:

```
    "@aws-amplify/api": "4.0.3",
    "@aws-amplify/api-graphql": "2.0.3",
    "@aws-amplify/auth": "4.0.3",
    "@aws-amplify/core": "4.1.1",
```

Comment: Hello, have you been able to solve this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: same issue. Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Go and check Cognito Identity Pool -> select the Identity Pool which includes your app name -->  Edit Identity Pool --> Authentication Provider --> Cognito --> check these values ===> User Pool Id, App client Id and Authenticated role selection.

In my case, setting the 'Authenticated role selection' to 'Use default role' solved the issue.